# RAML: Include example XML

Tags: json, xml, rest, dropwizard, raml

I have the following RAML snippet:

```
/myendpoint:
 post:
 description: Blah
 body:
  application/json:
   example: !include myendpoint_request.json
 responses:
  200:
   description: Blah
   body:
    application/xml:
        example: !include myendpoint_response.xml
```

My problem is that the resulting HTML shows *myendpoint_response.xml* included in a <code> block, and interpreted as XML content (not even visible) as opposed to the contents of *myendpoint_response.json* being rendered as a pretty-printed <pre> block.

**How can I include my XML file as pretty-printed XML?**

I'm using the following libraries:

- org.raml:raml-parser:0.8.10
- net.ozwolf:dropwizard-raml-view:3.0.3
- Java 8
- Groovy 3.1.30

Comment: The raw RAML seems to be generated just fine, it's the viewing the one that doesn't seem to work. Any ideas at all?

Comment: What resulting HTML? Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/raml2html ?

Comment: The RAML JSON is rendered as HTML using net.ozwolf:dropwizard-raml-view v3.0.3. Nothing NodeJS-related.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the precision, there are so many tools that transform RAML to HTML :)

Comment: @user2865130 Just one hint - sometime, when you have an XML document, it may be too wide - and the question is, how to reformat it to fit reasonable width. For me, the best reformatting tool is tidy (with --xml option and possibly some more). I always reformat my XMLs before including them into final documentation.

Comment: Hi @JanVlcinsky, thanks for the good advice. Unfortunately, I've tried formatting dummy XML with one small root element without success. Ideas and suggestions are very welcome at this point!

Comment: Hi @damelines See https://bitbucket.org/snippets/tamtamresearch/6LkqG - it contains tidy.conf file we use for formatting XML documents. See instructions in comments of that config file.